# adding events to random buttons of the keyboard

Tags: random, javafx, actionlistener, keyevent, eventhandler

Hello guys i really need your help . I want to make some program in javafx so i need to add listener to random generated button on the keyboard. For example :

i don't want to add some action if user type enter but i want to add action to some random button and nobody would know which is that button . so the user need to click every single button on the keyboard to find out which is that button.How would he knows that this is the correct button ?  - > well the program will be executed , when he click on the wrong button -> nothing will happen.

Comment: @slugmandrew i tried this :  pane.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,  ev -> {  if(ev.getCode() ==    KeyCode.ENTER)               });     well it shouldn't be "ENTER" , it should be some random button .

Comment: This isn't really a question within the scope of this forum. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question Can you [edit] the question to show what you have tried, explain in what ways it didn't work, and generally reformulate it so that it is more specific?

Comment: @James_D  i wrote the example of my code in the comment to slugmandrew .

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private void handleKeyPress(KeyEvent ke) {
    String text = ke.getText();
    KeyCode code = ke.getCode();
    if ( ke.isControlDown() || ke.isMetaDown() ) {
       //DO something for example
    }

}
```